# SpecFlow with NUnit: SetUp method runs twice

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, automated-tests, specflow

I installed SpecFlow and SpecRun recently on top of NUnit. I had a bit of trouble with references and Nuget packages but finally my tests run again. But this time whenever I run test (SpecFlow feature) my TestBase [SetUp] method once it reaches end runs again, resulting with opening browser window again. Test runs to the end with second attempt. Any one had similar problem?

I was checking solutions that point to PDB files as I see this popping up in Debug window but non seemed to work. Also, in Immediate Window I see this: `Step into: Stepping over non-user code`

I'm running test under recent version of SpecFlow v2.1.0 and NUnit3.21 against WebDriver v2.53.

Comment: Which hook of SpecFlow are you using for setup?

Comment: [SetUp] [BeforeScenario] and [TearDown] [AfterScenario]. I'm using both for NUnit and SpecFlow.

Comment: That is the problem. NUnit calls it once because if finds his attributes and SpecFlow calls in once because of the Hook- Attributes.

Comment: I should leave NUnit hooks right?

Comment: Do you have other NUnit tests/non SpecFlow that needs that code gets executed? If yes= take the NUnit Attributes, if no = take the SpecFlow Attributes

Comment: Ok. I'm marking it as resolved however... I must admit this was weird as I my SpecFlow tests run no problem yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference. NUnit and SpecFlow hooks are mutually exclusive. Make sure you run your tests with attributes specific for providers you want to run test with.